# Should I wear hijab in my house If I take care of a male orphan?

Tags: hijab, orphans

When the orphan become a teen
does the mother and all the puber girl in house should wear hijab inside their own  house?

since the orphan isn't a mahram

Comment: The orphan is not Mahram. So you must cover yourself even in your house if you take care of a male orphan.

Answer (score 1):

If u want to wear hijab then that's  very good. Yes after when a boy hits puberty. He becomes a non-mahram. So if the the boy has it puberty then all of the women who are non-mahram to him should cover themselves. The hair, arms, legs, chest etc. Hair should be covered in front of the orphan it is mandatory.

And marry not women whom your fathers married, except what has already passed; indeed it was shameful and most hateful, and an evil way. Forbidden to you (for marriage) are: your mothers, your daughters, your sisters, your paternal aunts, your maternal aunts, brother's daughters, sister's daughters, your foster mothers, your sisters from suckling, mothers of your spouses, your step-daughters from your those spouses you have entered into them but if you have not entered into them then there is no blame on you, spouses of your sons from your own loins and that you add two sisters except that has passed; indeed God is forgiving and merciful. Quran (An-Nisa 22-23):

So a girl can only not cover up infront her mahrams e.g:- Father, Brother, Husband, Son. Otherwise you should cover up yourself in front of the orphan.If u want wear hijab that's a good decision. Otherwise u can also wear dupatta that cover your hair, arms and chest.

Answer (score 1):

If the boy is immature and discriminating, the discriminating boy has no duty and his view of the woman is flawless; But as a precaution, the woman should cover her body and hair from the discriminating boy whose gaze on the woman arouses his lust.
But if the boy has reached the age of puberty, the woman should cover her hair and body other than her face and hands from a non-mahram man.

Ref: https://hadana.ir/%D8%AD%DA%A9%D9%85-%D9%BE%D9%88%D8%B4%D8%B4-%D8%B2%D9%86-%D8%AF%D8%B1-%D9%85%D9%82%D8%A7%D8%A8%D9%84-%D9%BE%D8%B3%D8%B1-%D9%86%D8%A7%D8%A8%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%BA/#i